Two switch forward converter with transient spikes on gate to source voltage - Part Deux
This post is about a similar problem seen in this  similar post
This 2 switch forward unit has a 750V input, 72 volt output and was tested at 10 and 15 amps out.
This new board doesn't have the challenge of being a single layer PCB as in the older post linked above.  Similar to the old power, when at a 500V DC link it has a significant voltage drop on the gate signal and then oscillates

We are using Micsig DP10013 Isolated probes to measure both of these traces. The yellow trace is the transformer primary at 250 V/div and the red trace is the gate to kelvin on the transistor at 5 V/div
When DC Link voltage is increased to its nominal 750 volts, there is a more significant gate to kelvin voltage drop but the oscilation mostly goes away.

Also this is only happening on the gate for the high side switch, not on the low side switch.  At 500V the low side switch is below.

Below is a picture of the gate drive area of the board, the high and low side gate circuits are symetrical.

This link is for a pdf document in google drive with many more pictures of 3 different tests with different snubbers on both the freewheeling diode and the transformer primary.
None of the changes we made seem to change this high side gate anomoly, we did add a 10nF cap between the gate and the kelvin pin which was installed for all of these pictures.
This link is for a pdf of the schematic.
The transformer is wound with the primary split on each side of the secondary (P-S-P) so we don't believe the transformer has excessive leakage inductance.
The primary winding snubber appears to be doing a very good job of reducing the spike and rining on the transformer so I'm at a loss of what would cause this spike in only the high side and leave the low side with what appears to be a normal Miller plateau.
Thanks for any help.
Dave

How are you measuring the high side gate waveform?

For scope images, please include time base and vertical scales.  Also include a legend to explain what voltage or node each channel is connected to, ie: what does the yellow trace represent, what does the red trace represent?

We are using Micsig DP10013 Isolated probes to measure both of these traces.  The yellow trace is the transformer primary at 250 V/div and the red trace is the gate to kelvin on the transistor at 5 V/div

And what is the horizontal scale?

The middle image: This does not show the yellow trace.  Please include that.

What you are seeing could be an artefact of the common-mode signal that the differential probe is trying to reject.  I suggest test your differential probe for common-mode rejection.  You can do this as follows:
Use the same test set-up as you did to take the first and second scope images.  Repeat the measurements, and confirm that you see the same results as you posted.
Then, move the probe input that is on the MOSFET gate pin over to the MOSFET source pin, ie: both inputs of the diff probe are now connected on the same pin.  Repeat the experiment, and post the images.
In all cases, ensure that the yellow trace is looking at the same voltage as you posted previously.
For scope images, please include time base and vertical scales.  Also include a legend to explain what voltage or node each channel is connected to, and a schematic, so your readers know exactly what the yellow trace represents, what does the red trace represents.

I wanted to thank everyone who responded.  There was a lot of good comments, the most significant suggestion was reminding us to check our probe for common mode noise, and its so simple to measure when you catch up and pay attention :-(
Also we were switching with the lowest gate resistor recomended by the manufacturer, now we've slowed down the turn on and kept the turn off as fast as possible with its own turn off gate resistor and diode.  The red line below is the transformer primary, and the yellow is the gate resistor 
The next image is the common mode noise referenced to the transformer primary signal.  The transformer would have been operating at 750 volts, and if you mentally use the common mode trace to 'adjust' the gate signal, you will see the typical miller platue and what I believe is a reasonable gate signal at 15 volts.

